# how to detect duplicates in arrays & print non duplicates?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, duplicates, conditional-statements

```
    void main ()
    {
        int x[19]={0}, i=0, y=0, u=0, p;
        while (i<=19)
        {
            scanf("%d",&x[i]);
            i=i+1;
        }
        for (i=u;i<=19;i++)
        {
            if (x[y]!=x[i+1])
                p=x[y];
                else
                {
                   u++;
                   y++;
                }
        }
        printf("%d",p);
    }
```

So I used this to check for duplicates & it should print non duplicates, but as you can see this works if all are duplicates but one, as in 
        x[0]=1 x[1]=1 x[3]=9 x[4]=1 ... x[19]=1;

```
    prints 
      9
```

So how to print non duplicates ? Any help ?

Comment: Side note: try making it a habit to not use single letter variable names.

Comment: O(n2) or sort or hashtable.

Comment: @Pawel depending on the requirements, this would also be a great application for a probabilistic data structure (bloom-filter).

Comment: "As you can see" ... sorry, I can't see anything. It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @Eiko he only prints one non-duplicate. However even after fixing that it would still not work because the list is unsorted.

Comment: That code almost looks like it's coming right of an obfuscator. It hides its intention quite well.

Comment: Any memory requirement or time complexity? What is array size? What is MAX value inside array?

Comment: no memory requirements nor time complexity, array size is 19, minimum value 10 & maximum value 100.
I haven't added this min/max restriction, still trying to make it work first. @Mazeryt

Comment: So it needs to be sorted say in ascending order before applying the condition? @Eiko

Comment: The code invokes unfunded behaviour be reading beyond an objects memory. This `while (i<=19)` should be `while (i<19)`. Even worth here `for (i=u;i<=19;i++)`.

Comment: I need the array to store in 20 integers so it should be `while (i<20)` or `while (i<=19)` as the array begins with " x[0] "

Comment: Doing `int x[19];` defines `x` to hold 19 elements. If you need 20 do `int x[20];`.

Comment: "*unfunded*" should have read "undefined" ...:}

Comment: The array index begins with 0; thus if I need to store 20 elements it'd be 19, so that it'd be (0 to 19) inclusive. @alk
Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just stating what I've studied.

Comment: How would you define an array for exactly ***one*** element? By doing `int x[0];`? No, you would do `int x[1];`. Still you are correct with that *accessing* the 1st element in `x` would be done by `int y = x[0];`. On definition of an array  the value inside the brackets give the number of element for the array. On accessing the array's elements the value inside the brackets gives its (***`0`-based***) index.

Comment: (Most) any IT guy has 10 fingers, and counts them 0 to 9 ... ;-)

Comment: Yes yes yes, thank you thank you thank you :D @alk
I lost it xD

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways is to sort the array to group the duplicates together. Then, as you go through the array you only print a number if its different from the number that came before.

```
// Print the unique elements of a sorted array:
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    if (i-1 >= 0 && arr[i] == arr[i-1]) { continue; }
    if (i+1 < N  && arr[i] == arr[i+1]) { continue; }
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

To sort the array you can use the [qsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qsort) function

Comment: This won't print only unique elements, but one of each element. But as the question is vague, maybe this is what he wants.

Comment: There is a easy fix for that: only print the number if its different than who came before *and* who comes after. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, but this only works properly if the array is sorted? @hugomg

Comment: Yes, sorting the array means that you only need to check the neighboring elements of the array to check for uniqueness (instead of needing to check every other element in the array). This speeds up the algorithm a lot: it becomes O(n log n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: It could also be much slower in practical application. It really depends on the input.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the easiest solution, simply nest an additional for-loop. However, this takes O(n^2). Depending on the size of the array, it could be beneficial to look at a fast sort.

```
void main() {
    int x[4] = { 1, 3, 2, 1 };

    size_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(x) / sizeof(int); i ++) {
        // Note that we only have to go to the last value before i.
        for (j = 0; j < i; j ++) {
            // We break if the value is a duplicate.
            if (x[i] == x[j])
                break;
        }

        // Check if the inner loop was break'ed (j < i) or not (j == i).
        if (j == i)
            printf("Unique: %i\n", x[i]);
    }
}
```

One more thing: only use `sizeof(x) / sizeof(int)` if the size of `x` is known during compilation. This is the case here, but don't use it with `malloc`.

Comment: It took me a while to study this, I just don't understand `sizeof(x) / sizeof(int)` what does this point out?

Comment: It's the dimension of your `x` array of ints, so 4. However, I added a warning to point out that this only works for statically allocated arrays.

Comment: ... only for statically allocated arrays, which have been declared in scope of you function (passing them as argument loses information about array size), to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main ()
{
    int num[20]={0}, i=0, n=0, index_num=0, init_incr=0, unique=0, n_uniq=1, temp, check=0;
    while (i<=19)
    {
        printf("%02d-  ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&num[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }
    for (index_num=0;index_num<19;index_num++)
    {
        for (n=init_incr+index_num;n<19;n++)
        {
            if (num[index_num]!=num[index_num+1] && num[index_num]!=num[index_num-1])
            {
                check++;
                temp=num[index_num];
                unique=temp;
                for (;n_uniq<=check;n_uniq++)
                printf("\tunique %02d  = %d\n", n_uniq, unique);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help :D